# Engage Reports & Engage Team Reports are from different connected apps. How can we get the counts to match between the two tabs?

Tags: reporting, pardot

I have a client that uses Engage and Pardot. They are asking me to solve for discrepancies between the Engage Reports and Engage Team Reports tabs.

[image: Engage Team Reports] [image: Engage Reports]

I understand that Engage Team Reports comes from the EngageReports installed package and Engage Reports comes from the Pardot installed package, but I cannot really see definitively where the data is sourced from.

Is there a way to reconcile these or is this a known gap with Engage/Pardot? Any and all insight here is appreciated.

Comment: They're different reports, count may not match by design.. Engage Team shows aggregated stats filtered by your role on the team whereas Engage (User) shows individual stats. Take a look at the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.pardot_sf_engage_reporting_parent.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes, that does make sense, but even on team reports, we can drill into one specific user and that's where the discrepancy is. Same user, delivered count is different. I did just notice that the User report is only for emails sent with Engage Campaigns, so perhaps that is the difference, if they are sending other ways, that would reflect in Team Reports only.